# Uploading a file using powershell and updating column values

Tags: 2010, powershell, column, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file from a local drive to a sharepoint doc lib, this much I have been able to find, however, I also want to update a column relative to the file, foe example, I have a company column that I want to populate along with the upload, how would I modify this powershell script to do so? Any help would be awesome!

```
 Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

 function UploadFile($Web, $DocLibName, $FilePath)
 {
   $List = $Web.GetFolder($DocLibName) 
   $Files = $List.Files
   $FileName = $FilePath.Substring($FilePath.LastIndexOf("\")+1) 
   $File= Get-ChildItem $FilePath
   $Files.Add($DocLibName +"/" + $FileName,$File.OpenRead(),$false)
}
$SiteUrl = "https://foo.foo.com"
$Web = Get-SPWeb $SiteUrl
UploadFile $Web "DocLib" "C:\x.pdf"
Write-Host "Documents Uploaded to $SiteUrl"
$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: THank you, I get the following error: > Exception calling "GetFile" with "1" argument(s): "Value does not fall
> within t he expected range." At line:9 char:53
> + [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile]$spFile = $Web.GetFile <<<< ("/" + $folder.Url
> + "/" + $File.Name)
> + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException update file properties ... > Cannot index into a null array. At line:22 char:15
> + $spFile.Item[ <<<< "Title"] = "Reference Document"
> + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (Title:String) [], RuntimeExce ption
> + FullyQua

Comment: I did, due to space limitations I did not include my script

Comment: These are the fields I updated with my own:

Comment: $spFile.Item["Title"] = "Reference Document"
 $SiteUrl = "http://dhaval-pc:2011/"
 UploadFile $Web "Proposal" "C:\test.pdf"

Answer (score 5):

For this, an understanding of Server Object Model (SSOM) is needed. When you upload a file, you get the reference to the [SPFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.aspx) object. The corresponding [SPListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx) can be accessed through its [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.item.aspx) member

```
$spFile = $folder.Files.Add(...
$spFile.Item["SomeColumn"] = "SomeValue"
$spFile.Item.Update()
```

**Try this complete script :**

```
 Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

function UploadFile($Web, $DocLibName, $FilePath)
{

  $Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true;
  $List = $web.Lists[$DocLibName]
  $folder = $List.RootFolder
  #$Files = $List.Files
  $FileName = $FilePath.Substring($FilePath.LastIndexOf("\")+1) 
  $File= Get-ChildItem $FilePath

 [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile]$spFile = $Web.GetFile("/" + $folder.Url + "/" + $File.Name)

if($spFile.Exists -eq $false)
   {
    #Open file
    $fileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $File.FullName)).OpenRead()
    #Add file
    write-host "Copying file " $File.Name " to " $folder.ServerRelativeUrl "..."
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile]$spFile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" + $File.Name, [System.IO.Stream]$fileStream, $true)
    write-host "Success"
    #Close file stream
    $fileStream.Close()
  }

 write-host "update file properties " $spFile.Name "..."
 $spFile.Item["Title"] = "Reference Document"
 $spFile.Item.Update()
 $Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $false;

 }
 $SiteUrl = "http://dhaval-pc:2011/"
 $Web = Get-SPWeb $SiteUrl
 UploadFile $Web "Proposal" "C:\test.pdf"
 Write-Host "Documents Uploaded to $SiteUrl"
 $Web.Dispose()
```

Comment: how can this great script be modified to create and upload to subfolders? Regards Lars